# Some user information not loaded when searching for users in Reputation Leagues

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-exchange, reputation-leagues

When I search (like "smi") for users in the [reputation leagues](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/alltime/stackoverflow) of stackoverflow, the information of some users is not loaded and the loading symbol ("Loading user information") gets displayed.

I´m using Chrome 24.0.1312.52. Executing the search again (Navigate to SearchBox and hit Enter) finally displays the user information.

(Click on image for zoom.)
[image: Loading user information]

Comment: Worth to mention that those are not all users, just "top users" so for example you won't find users who don't have 200 rep in any account. And +1, just reproduced it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I *think* this is fixed now. I wasn't able to reproduce it locally, and reproduced it only inconsistently on the live site.

The issue had to do with the timing surrounding adding two `script` blocks, for which one is dependent on the other, to the DOM via jQuery's [html](http://api.jquery.com/html/) function.

Comment: Pretty certain it's fixed, as I was able to reproduce it just fine before and now it works OK.

Comment: Update: same bug still exists only *for your own profile picture and name* when you switch sites. (to a site where you have account)

Comment: I can confirm that the bug is resolved. User information is now loaded.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Can you be more specific what you mean or open a new question for the problem

Comment: @Jehof never mind, too minor anyway.

Comment: This issue is not fixed - I'm experiencing it right now on the Space Exploration site. Also, my displayed score is a bit out of date.