# Most user cards are not loading on the Reputation Leagues

Tags: bug, status-completed, stackexchange.com, reputation-leagues, user-card

I've tried on Chrome and Firefox to get [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tour) to list users in the "leagues", e.g., https://stackexchange.com/leagues/65/alltime/stats/2010-07-19?sort=reputationchange&page=3 and most entries show the "circle of death" as in the image below. What is going on?

[image: screenshot of user cards loading forever in Cross Validated]

Note, a similar problem (where only the current user wasn't loading), without browser information, for different Stack Exchange sites has been also reported [User profile is not loading Stack Exchange reputation league page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/396992/user-profile-is-not-loading-stack-exchange-reputation-league-page)

Comment: I can also reproduce this on Safari on iOS.

Comment: @Arulkumar No, it merely asks a similar but different question. My question pertains to Cross Validated. The other question documents a problem which may have the same cause but on Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Exchange. Neither question has been answered thus not closing this post until the problem, which may be system wide, is addressed would be appreciated. Consider it supplementary information, please.

Comment: @Arulkumar Moreover, the existence of a potentially similar problem has prompted me to add the `bug` tag since some sort of problem is confirmed. The evidence here is also helpful in the sense that three browsers, so far, are herein reported to have the same problem, making it more likely to be a source code `bug`, and not a browser problem.

Comment: @Arulkumar I agree with the author here - this might be a different cause given that the staff comment on the post you link says it's a Gravatar issue but examining the avatars that don't load here, those include direct Imgur uploads as well. If they indeed turn out to be the same cause, staff can close it when answering.

Comment: Looks like the bug escalated, now most cards are not loading (at least for me) and on all sites I've checked, so this report is better suited for that, hence reopening.

Comment: @ShadowWizardLoveZelda This either is or is not a duplicate of the [first one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/396992/271271). If it is a duplicate and you're going to reopen this one, then you should close the [first one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/396992/271271) as a duplicate of this one.

Comment: My guess is some big server side cache that used to hold the users data got stuck/reset and the query to fill it up is heavy. After a user is loaded, they'll show up, but most are still loading.

Comment: @Makyen fair point, done. In case it's different issue (though I doubt it), the developer confirming it can easily reopen.

Comment: @ShadowWizardLoveZelda Look, the rules for closure are there for a reason. However, sometimes, like when a bug is active and not addressed, confirmation in the form of independent validation is needed. Both posts can be closed when the bug is addressed, and before that occurs, leave both open, please.

Comment: No, I agree with @Makyen as this appears to come from same root cause. Closing does not affect chance of fixing, it needs a status review tag first anyway.

Comment: Also, looks like something very similar [happened before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164000/some-user-information-not-loaded-when-searching-for-users-in-reputation-leagues)

Comment: @ShadowWizardLoveZelda Thanks, the prior occurrence is important in that the problem perhaps can be fixed again, maybe better this time?

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem (on Space Exploration) since last night to present.

Comment: I confirm the problem on Meta Stack Exchange Leagues for Firefox using iMac. Most links show circles of death now, including mine, as of Feb 24, 2024.

Comment: @Carl problem is, previous time nothing was really fixed. If you'll read the developer's answer carefully, you'll see he wasn't able to reproduce, and it just "fixed itself" at some point.

Comment: @ShadowWizardLoveZelda Maybe that will happen again. We'll see.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I know. However, as a maverick I usually relate how things should be, rather than how they are. Consider, "Left open as a duplicate" would be more semantically correct, and would serve the same purpose. Moreover, `status-completed` already exists but is misused as in https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164000/341152, which issue, seemingly reoccurring here, was never a `bug-fix`. Some attention should be paid to what is said so as not to create jargon that is unique enough that ordinary language becomes uninterpretable.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Relax, I am not arguing. Thank you for your explanation, I got the point long ago. Is there something you can do to help get the site working more normally?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Short story, I once took over running a division. I improved it to the point where it was the best running division in the organization. I took a lot of flak, and when I spoke to the CEO about that she said, "What were you expecting; *Gratitude*?" Cleaning up other peoples messes is never appreciated, even if you live in a cave. For example, downvotes are not worth as much as upvotes precisely because they are not as informed, or informative. And yes, I would increase the downvote minimum reputation level a bit more than it is already to increase quality.

Comment: Carl, I see your point and I would be really thrilled (really, not joking here) if you'll take Stack Exchange and change it from the core to be something better. However, in the way it's built and working now, I just fully agree with @Aaron, he said exactly what I would have said either, and in a better way. :)

Comment: @AaronBertrand also, can you throw a status-review tag here? (staff bit should be enough for that, afaik.)

Comment: @AaronBertrand Thank-you in advance for your efforts. I am heartened that you are taking this on, that you care about issues. There are so many issues that it is disheartening.

Comment: as someone following this question to get notified about the fix to the problem, getting numerous pings about wider discussion about bugs being fixed is annoying. could that discussion please be taken elsewhere?

Comment: Can someone weigh in on whether this problem is likely to be fixed by an end-user action such as erasing the browser's cache or cookies?

Comment: @phil1008 No, cache and cookies have no effect on Safari, which browser I almost never use. The problem is with the website.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### tl;dr

The issue is now fixed. Thanks for the report!

#### Some details for anyone curious

For reputation leagues on stackexchange.com, we load and cache users on a background thread that doesn't have the full site and user context available. This code is separate from the main Q&A app, so when we added a check in the method that validates profile image URLs that required that context, it caused a null reference exception that went unnoticed.  We've refactored the checks, so all user cards are once again loading correctly.

Comment: Thank-you very much for your kind attention to this problem and for participating in its repair. The bug is now fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the details. Missed them in recent bug fixes.

Answer (score 2):

I discovered that you can improve the reputation leagues page with a work-a-round. If you first go to the "users" page on the site...

[image]

.. you can identify the names of some of the users that are not showing up on the reputation leagues page.

Then, if you search for one of those users on the reputation leagues page, and **enter their full username**, the card will often populate (not always though). Once a card has initially populated, it seems to stick around even when you aren't searching for a specific user.

[image]

As I said, it's not a real fix, but perhaps it's a helpful workaround for some users in the meantime.

... maybe also a clue that will help devs figure out the root cause.

P.S> Interestingly, this workaround did not work for my own card.

Comment: For what it is worth, if one left clicks on any particular "circle of death" the link to that users web page is executed allowing one to see who it is. However, that doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: It's working for me today! Possibly a fix was rolled out or something was reset.

Comment: Indeed, read the accepted answer by Adam Lear above.